# Problem facing while accessing already created project into the workspace

Tags: android, compiler-errors

This is the problem am facing since many days. am trying to manage that but not able to solve that. while am try to access the project which is existing project into workspace then am getting some kind of error at the "@override" tag and when remove that the error disappear and single error will be shown at the application name and that cannot be removed. Am doing for the mean while is try to copy all the code from the each java file and paste it to another project that was created newly.

Can any one help me in this concern. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is actually Java-related and not specifically Android-related. You should add that tag to your question as well. Anyway, either @Override is incorrect at that position or your class does not implement requested methods. Post the code that is giving those errors, please.

Comment: the code is fine . Even i want to specify other related problem i.e., when ever i create the new project there is a error always showing and to solve that  i will go to Built path and say use source folder then the error disappear. But when am importing the project the problem was not resolved. Please help me.

Comment: Define what the error is and post the code that's giving the errors.

Comment: Thank you for taking the responsibility. The problem is straight forward when ever i create or import the project then there is a kind of error which is there even though i have not written a  single line of code. i am trying to remove the error in the case when i created the new project by going into the "built path" and go to "use a source folder" then the error is removed,but not done in the case of importing the new file

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mU1Xf.png             and that is the way i will get error even though i dont have any errors in the code

Comment: What's R.java doing on your package? That's an auto-generated file... Should be on gen/ folder IIRC. IMHO you have a wrong setup on your ADT plugin or Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to JDK for this what you have to do is from menu options choose

**Window > Preference** then navigate to node displayed in below image and set **"Compiler compliance level as 1.6"**

[image]

Comment: It is as same as you have posted. But the error is same. Can you suggest any other way

Comment: Even i want to specify other related problem i.e., when ever i create the new project there is a error always showing and to solve that i will go to Built path and say use source folder then the error disappear. But when am importing the project the problem was not resolved. Please help me.

Comment: Ok I faced such issues earlier dont know if that helps as its some kind of sdk bug I think, there is file in every android project named "default.properties" which is not created some times is this the case with you

Comment: oh! ok... but default.properties is there in the project.My other friends also has the same problem.Any way if you get the solution,please try to mail me. getdestiny9@gmail.com